# conventions for rails app documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, documentation-generation

I known that it's more a state of art than a technical question, but I'm looking for some good templates to document  model relation, validations, method for the models and controllers of my rails app.

Are there any conventions/best practice/examples to do that ?

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RDoc to self-document your code.  It'll take your code comments and make documentation for your project.

- http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyDoc

It's pretty neat.

I'm not sure there's much use in documenting validations and relations... Your Ruby source code is already incredibly readable in that regard.